# Regular expression to keep some matches, remove others

Tags: regex, r

I'm having a trouble with this regular expression.  Consider the following vector.

```
> vec <- c("new jersey", "south dakota", "virginia:chincoteague",
           "washington:whidbey island", "new york:main")
```

Of those strings that contain a `:`, I would like to keep only the ones with `main` after `:`,  resulting in

```
[1] "new jersey" "south dakota" "new york:main"
```

So far, I've only been able to get there with this ugly nested nightmare, which is quite obviously far from optimal.

```
> g1 <- grep(":", vec)
> vec[ -g1[grep("main", grep(":", vec, value = TRUE), invert = TRUE)] ]
# [1] "new jersey"    "south dakota"  "new york:main"
```

How can I write a single regular expression to keep `:main` but remove others containing `:` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `|` (Pick one that contains `:main` or that does not contains `:` at all):

```
> vec <- c("new jersey", "south dakota", "virginia:chincoteague",
+            "washington:whidbey island", "new york:main")
> grep(":main|^[^:]*$", vec)
[1] 1 2 5
> vec[grep(":main|^[^:]*$", vec)]
[1] "new jersey"    "south dakota"  "new york:main"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this single simple regex:

```
^[^:]+(?::main.*)?$
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/wO2oX6)

Not sure about the exact R code, but something like

```
grepl("^[^:]+(?::main.*)?$", subject, perl=TRUE);
```

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- The `[^:]+` matches all chars that are not a colon
- The optional non-capturing group `(?::main.*)?` matches a colon, `main` and any chars that follow
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

Comment: FYI Added explanation. :)